# Other action in ZF IndexController

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, object

I can't have another action than indexAction in my IndexController.
I try to create another controller than IndexController, it's doesn't works.
example.com link to my index controller, index action.
example.com/index doesn't works.

What can I do ?

```
require_once 'application/controllers/AbstractController.php';

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->testMessage = "test";
        echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
}
```

-> works, print: test /

```
require_once 'application/controllers/AbstractController.php';

class MemberController extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->testMessage = "test";

    }
}
```

-> Doesn't works

Comment: Please provide code for `AbstractController`. And do you have mod_rewrite enabled and `.htaccess` in public folder?

Comment: What means "doesn't works"? Nothing happens? White page? Error? Do you have a phtml-template called "views/scripts/member/index.phtml"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the default application setup with the standard htaccess in place, then your URLs will map to

```
hostname/controller/action/arg/val/arg/val/…
```

with the default controller being the IndexController and the default Action being the indexAction. In other words:

```
myurl.com/ -> IndexController indexAction
```

To call the Member Controller you have to do

```
myurl.com/member
```

To call any other action than the indexAction you have to do

```
myurl.com/member/other
```

You can influence how ZF maps URLs to your controller with

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: myurl.com/member and myurl.com/index -> The requested URL /member was not found on this server.

The .htaccess in the public folder (same level than the index.php) contains:
> Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt)$ index.php

Sure I have a phtml-templates "views/scripts/member/index.phtml" :)

Thanks !

Comment: @denis Are you sure the htaccess is actually enabled? If this is shared hosting, your hosting service might have disabled it. Also, have a look at http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html